# How to change workspace directory when upgrading from Eclipse 32 to 64

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, upgrade

Oops.  I am admittedly new to Eclipse.  I recently upgraded to Win7-64 from XP-32 (old Dell dual-processor Work station).  So thought I could simply install Eclipse-64, install all plugins. and redirect Eclipse-64 to point to new workspace directory containing the old project files.  Changing path is easy enough, but Eclipse package/project explorer sees nothing in my new directory.  Should I cut paste all existing files and put in default directory then import to newly created directory.  Should I 'package' the old files and use as class library?  Should I re-install Eclipse-32 and start over?  Any expert advice here would be greatly appreciated.  I have read all posts regarding this issue, but believe there may me a 32/64 issue here.  Hope I'm wrong and transition will be smooth. I don't want to lose access to all my 'code in progress' or go back to Eclipse-32. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried to import your projects?

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Switch Workspace -> Other.  Follow the prompts.

The Eclipse UI is complex.

Answer (score 0):

I had new directory path correctly assigned in Eclipse-64.  But had empty project explorer view. So cut and pasted old project folders from newly created path to default installation workspace for E64.  Then 'import' message said I needed to create project folder in order to do that.  No problem.  Then I imported all folders from old Eclipse version to new directory path and wallah!  Opened bin class file and all code is there!  I may have screwed up in overwriting version info and other E32 files over existing E64 files here in new install workspace folder, but at  least I know how to do this now.  So thinking of re-installing E64 and 'all' plugins (a real pain), but at least I will know I am new-platform compatible and all will be good in my world.  As always, thanks for expert advice here.  The 'full' stack rules!